# I need some help about the dimensionality reduction method: Sparsity Preserving Projections (SPP)

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm, face-recognition, dimensionality-reduction

I am trying to reconstruct in Python the dimensionality reduction method called Sparsity Preserving Projections (SPP) based on the paper "[Sparsity preserving projections with applications to face recognition](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0031320309001964?via%3Dihub)" by Lishan Qiao, Songcan Chen and Xiaoyang Tan.

The steps are:
Load dataset (Yale B)
Split the dataset into training and testing sets and normalize
Apply PCA and preserve 98% of the total variance
Apply SPP (snpe) on the PCA transformed data
Evaluate using SVM, kNN

My problem is that what ever I do I get an accuracy score of ~3%.

```
def sparse_representation(X):
    # Initialize S matrix
    m, n = X.shape
    S = np.zeros((n, n))

    # Convert X to a matrix type that SPAMS can use
    X = np.asfortranarray(X, dtype=np.float64)

    # Set the parameters for SPAMS
    param = {'lambda1': 1e-6, 'numThreads': -1, 'mode': 2}

    # Loop through each sample to find s_i
    for i in tqdm(range(n)):
        # Define X_temp and x
        X_temp = np.delete(X, i, axis=1)
        x = X[:, i].reshape(-1, 1)

        # Use SPAMS to find the sparse representation
        s_i = spams.lasso(x, D=X_temp, return_reg_path=False, **param).toarray()

        # Check for negative values and take their absolute value
        s_i[np.where(s_i < 0)] = np.abs(s_i[np.where(s_i < 0)])

        # Check for near-zero values and set them to zero
        s_i[np.where(np.abs(s_i) < 1e-7)] = 0

        # Normalize the new s_i matrix
        s_i_norm = np.linalg.norm(s_i, ord=1)
        if s_i_norm != 0:  # Check if the norm is not zero
            s_i = s_i / s_i_norm

        # Add a zero to the place that has been checked
        s_i = np.insert(s_i, i, 0)

        # Store s_i in the S matrix
        S[:, i] = s_i.T
    return S
```

```
def snpe(X, n_components):
    S = sparse_representation(X)
    # Compute S_beta
    S_beta = S + S.T - S.T @ S

    # Solve the generalized eigenvalue problem
    A = X @ S_beta @ X.T
    B = X @ X.T
    epsilon = 1e-6  # Small positive value
    np.fill_diagonal(B, np.diag(B) + epsilon) #add positive value to the diagonal elements of B
    w, lamda = scipy.linalg.eigh(A,B)

    # Sort the eigenvalues and eigenvectors in descending order
    idx = np.argsort(w)[::-1]
    w = w[idx]
    lamda = lamda[:, idx]

    # Normalize the eigenvectors
    lamda = normalize(lamda, axis=1)

    return lamda[:, :n_components]
```

I have tried lots of minimize functions to find the sparse representation such as linear regression, Lasso, ElasticNet and still nothing.

The authors have implemented this method using Matlab and I am trying to reconstruct it in Python. For the Yale B dataset according to the paper I should be getting an accuracy of 94%.